# How to get HorizontalScrollView width

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I am developing an application which consists of horizontal-scroll-view,I want to get width of **HorizontalScrollView**.How i can achieve this? it is returning as zero for me

### in XMl in have like this.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:background="#00ff00" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#ff0000" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="#00ff00" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

In Java

```
public class TestApplication extends Activity{

    private HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testscroll);

        horizontalScrollView1 = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
        horizontalScrollView1.getRight();
        horizontalScrollView1.getWidth();

        System.out.println("horizontalScrollView1.getWidth();::>"+horizontalScrollView1.getWidth());
        System.out.println("horizontalScrollView1.getWidth();::1>"+horizontalScrollView1.getMeasuredWidth());
    }
```

I have tried Following methods can any one help me please.

Thanks 
Nikhil

Answer (score 2):

you can do it this way:

```
int width = 0;
ViewTreeObserver vto = horizontalScrollView1.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        width = horizontalScrollView1.getWidth();
    }
});
```

Hope to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `getWidth()` method try with `getMeasuredWidth()` it will help you i think

Comment: is there any view inside the linear layout

Comment: Once add any view inside layout add check

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve in this scenario:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    int width = horizontalScrollView1.getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = horizontalScrollView1.getMeasuredHeight();
    System.out.println("widrh::>"+width);
    System.out.println("height::>"+height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try like this

```
Log.d("TAG","scrollbar width: " + scrollView.getChildAt(0).getWidth());
Log.d("TAG","scrollbar height: " + scrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight());
```